# [dat]'s some terrible naming convention if you ask me

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I was recently looking for the [dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat) tag, which refer to the Dat protocol and found that people were using it to refer to files of data with .dat extension. 
I think it might be a normal confusion, but if we rename the [dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat) tag to [dat-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat-protocol), to explicitly talk about the Dat protocol, people would stop using it wrong.

Comment: In addition, a [tag:dat-file] tag might be a good idea, although I'm not sure if it's a useful tag to have since such a file can contain pretty much anything.

Comment: @Stijn I'm against a dat-file tag, for the reason you said. It's not a well-defined file format, and can contain about anything, so it doesn't add much to the question to have that tag. If it's binary (not text), one can use [tag:binaryfiles]. Else, one can try to find out how the file is structured, and use an appropriate tag for that structure.

Comment: [https://datproject.org/](https://datproject.org/)?

Comment: As Peter pointed, I'm talking about Dat project, not some file archive https://www.datprotocol.com/

Comment: Dat protocol, though.

Comment: [dat] ain't right

Comment: Nobody go time for [dat]

Comment: What is [dat] ?

Comment: Hard to think anything other than "This is what the project deserves for picking a three letter sequence already in such widespread use"

Comment: here come dat protocol

Comment: @Michael You should post this as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: DAT is, most frequently, Digital Audio Tape.

Comment: It was +9/-1 at the time I edited the title... you're welcome

Comment: [dat]'s a good idea I think.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There were only seven questions tagged with [dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat) so I took the liberty to re-tag them. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50457622/extracting-a-string-from-a-specific-position-from-a-dat-file), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236772/read-dat-ecg-file), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436749/why-the-weird-language), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229419/is-it-possible-to-import-dat-files-to-mysql) were obviously incorrect usage. I retagged the remaining three as [dat-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat-protocol).

[dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat) is now a synonym of [dat-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat-protocol).

[dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dat)'s a wrap